# What is the chemical potential in case of semiconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

What the chemical potential physically means? In case of semiconductors how is it relevant? What is the difference between chemical potential and fermi energy in case of semiconductors? What is the physics behind it? I know the mathematical stuff. But I couldn't get an intuitive understanding of this thing. If anyone could please explain, that will be a great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the Fermi level and the Fermi-Dirac distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/549577/understanding-the-fermi-level-and-the-fermi-dirac-distribution)

Comment: I read the post, but I am sorry that I am unable to grasp the thing. Can you please explain in a simpler language? Also, there is another post of similar nature: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351374/the-concept-of-fermi-level but I couldn't get what the author is trying to say by citing entropy of the system and fermi surface.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Concerning your lack of intuitive understanding, you're not alone.  Kittel put it pretty well in his solid state physics book:  "A vague discomfort at the thought of the chemical potential is still characteristic of a physics education."